# How to decrypt an encoded message when encryption algorithm is unknown

Tags: algorithm, encryption

Considering we have the following information:

```
BLOCK A : 8374928304
BLOCK B : 7719

Result : 239
```

The result is generated from those 2 blocks, but the algorithm is unknown.
However, I have several `block` & `result` pairs.
How would one go about finding out how is the result generated from those two blocks?

Comment: You have to look at all the different block pair/result sets, doing _lots_ of comparisons.  It's a form of analysis.  We can't give you any additional direction without more info, and may not be able to even then.

Comment: If this is all the information you have, there is no way to reverse engineer it. You don't know whether it's a hash, some random proprietary algorithm, `return 239`, a modulus operation, substitution... that's what came to mind within a minute, I'm sure you can come up with a dozen more that could result in this. Mathematically speaking, there's an infinite number of functions ZxZ->Z that produce 239 for that input.

Comment: And for any finite set of input-result pairs, there is an infinite number of functions ZxZ->Z that produce the provided result for each input.

Comment: Is this one of those hipster job postings? Like google's with the math formulas on the billboards? "Want a job at the NSA? Generalize a process for defeating all ciphers.. without any information.. omnipotently.." If I could do it, I don't think marking my answer as correct would a sufficient reward.

Comment: Assuming it's a widely used encryption algorithm that's employed, there's no way to figure out which algorithm was used, and even if you do, the information will be next to useless to you because there are no feasible analytical attacks on any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your success depends mostly on the sophistication of the entety that created the cypher/hashing scheme. Using only several input/output pairs to correctly identify the hashing scheme is in principle very difficult, as an infinite number of methods can be used to generate a given output from a given input.

Your only chance at discovering the hashing scheme is the hashing scheme is not very sophisticated and you can somehow guess what it is. Here are some very basic hashing schemes I would think to try, if I think that the hash creator is not very sophisticated:

- Simple [checksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum): compute the checksum of Block A / Block B. Try additions subtractions, etc.
- Taking the [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) of the two values, and then performing further function.

However, as you will see, the simple methods take more of your time to try and verify then you probably have on your hands. As an example, we might hypothesize that the hashing scheme is:

> Take block A, mod it by block B, and subtract 6040

This will work in the above case, but I strongly suspect is is not going to work on your other values.  We could then try:

> Take block A, mod it by block B+1, and subtract 1865

This will also work for the above values, but soon you will run out of patience. So without having a theory of what kind of hashing scheme your adversary might have picked, this is an extremely difficult problem to solve.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of encryption is to hide data from attackers who either don't know the algorithm or don't know some specific piece of information for how to use the algorithm to decrypt the data (for instance, in public/private key cryptography, the algorithm is well-known but the private key is obviously not). If you don't know the algorithm but are able to reverse-engineer it, then the algorithm is not very secure. Therefore if you are dealing with a well-designed encryption algorithm, it is statistically impossible to do what you're asking for.

Comment: If the algorithm is well designed, he can know every detail about it but not the key and won't be able to break it analytically. No security by obscurity.

Comment: Well, yeah, I mentioned that. But either way what he's asking for is impossible.